# Can char contains more than 32767 values in java

Tags: java, types

As char data type in java is of 2 byte which are equals to 16 bits when we convert these bits into ASCII then that would be -32768_0_32767 but when I'm trying to store more values than there is no compilation error want to know why not a compilation occurs??

Here is the code snap:
[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Comment: Your output for float and double is somewhat misleading; to calculate the representable range you need to know the size of the exponent field.  It's correct for "different values" but that's not the useful thing to know about floating point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `char` data type is the only primitive type in java that is defined as being **unsigned**. It can hold values from 0 to 65535. Try it:

```
char c = 65535; // works
char d = -1; // compilation error; cast required
```

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, `boolean` isn't signed either :-)

Comment: @StephenC That is some expert level pedantism :) – yup. It's so easy to forget boolean is one of the primitives, you got me there.

Comment: It is pedantry, not pedantism.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Char primitive data type of java has a size of 2 bytes. It ranges from 0 to 65536 as it is unsigned.
[For more, refer this link](https://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-primitive-data-types)